# Relation between congruence and remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I’m self-studying number theory using George Andrew’s textbook. I’m at the chapter of congruence modulo. There is one or two parts that I couldn’t quite figure out. Wonder if someone could point things out for me.

By definition, if $c≠0$, $a≡b \pmod c$ provided that $(a-b)/c$ is an integer. That is $c \mid (a-b)$.

If $a= 5$, $b=-3$, $c=8$

5 is congruent to -3 modulo 8, $5≡-3 \pmod 8$ since $(5-(-3))/8$ is an integer of $1$.

I also read on Wikipedia that "Equivalently, a ≡ b mod n can also be thought of as asserting that the remainders of the division of both a and b by n are the same." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

If that’s the case, using the same example. The remainder of (5/8) is 5, while the remainder of (-3/8) is -3. They are not the same.

I think I’m missing a point here. Could someone please help point out where my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: By definition the remainder $\,r\,$ when dividing by $\,n\,$ lies in the range $\,0\le r < n.\ $ Therefore the remainder of $\, {-}3\div 8\,$ is $\,5,\,$ not $\,-3.\ \ \ $

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: In this specific case I have changed the original title "Number Theory - Congruence Modulo" to "Relation between congruence and remainder"; I believe that the latter describes the question better. If you are able to come up with a better title, please, go ahead and edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

I quote the definition of Euclidean division for integers given in Wikipedia: "Given two integers $a$ and $b$, with $b\neq 0$, there exist unique ***integers*** $q$ and $r$ such that $a= bq + r$ and $0\le r < |b|$, where $|b|$ denotes the absolute value of $b$".

In the example we have $5=8.0+5$ and $-3=8.(-1)+5$, so the remainders are the same.